# How to Export Selection from Telerik RadGridView to Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I want to export only the selected rows of my RadGridView to Excel. I have managed to export everything, but If the user has selected rows I want only to export those rows from the RadGridView to Excel. Here is my code: (The Todo should be implemented)

```
 public void Execute_OpenExportView(RadGridView gridViewExport)
    {
        if (gridViewExport==null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string extension = "xlsx";
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog()
        {
            DefaultExt = extension,
            Filter = String.Format("{1} files (*.{0})|*.{0}|All files(*.*)|*.*", extension, "Excel"),
            FilterIndex = 1,
            AddExtension = true,
            Title = "Export to Excel",
            //FileName = 
        };


        //TODO export the selected rows from RadGRidView
        if (gridViewExport.SelectedItems.Count!=0)
        {


        }

        if (dialog.ShowDialog()==true)
        {
            using (Stream stream = dialog.OpenFile())
            {
                gridViewExport.ExportToXlsx(stream,
                    new GridViewDocumentExportOptions()
                    {
                        ShowColumnFooters = true,
                        ShowColumnHeaders = true,
                        ShowGroupFooters = true,
                        AutoFitColumnsWidth = true,
                    });
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in **Items** property of the **GridViewDocumentExportOptions** and pass the **SelectedItems** collection of RadGridView to it. Please checkout the [ExportFormat.Xlsx](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/export/export-xlsx) topic in the Telerik UI for WPF documentation for more information.

This would be the solution in your code:

```
 if (dialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            using (Stream stream = dialog.OpenFile())
            {
                gridViewExport.ExportToXlsx(stream,
                    new GridViewDocumentExportOptions()
                    {
                        Items = gridViewExport.SelectedItems,
                        ShowColumnFooters = true,
                        ShowColumnHeaders = true,
                        ShowGroupFooters = true,
                        AutoFitColumnsWidth = true,
                    });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I spent hours on this, and it is so simple.